# How to reinstall MySQL in Windows but keep all data and configuration

Tags: mysql

MySQL server was working fine yesterday until the windows update today.
I've been looking a solution and tried different ones. I'm running on a Windows 11 OS.

**Note that I cannot start the service so I cannot backup my database using mysqldump**

What I've tried so far:

1. Reconfiguring MySQL Server using the community installer
2. Repair the installed program in Control Panel - Programs and Features

What I'm planning more to do:

1. Delete the previously installed windows update

I've checked the `C:\ProgramData\MySQL` folder and found my databases with **.IDB** extension and configuration files. I was wondering if these files were necessary to backup my data.

Comment: Check your logs before doing it

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @nelsonsule It's MySQL

Comment: I suggest you go into your installation directory > bin folder and execute mysqldump command directly. you don't need the service started to be able to do this

Comment: @nelsonsule It can't connect to MySQL Server.

Comment: I was able to resolve that using that by running mysqldump command from the installation directory without mysql server running as a service when I had such problems. However, consider re-installation. if it does not work try installing XAMPP then copy for data folder from the previous installation to your mysql directory in xampp